# What kind of code is this? C or C++

Tags: c++, c

I have written some code for my own practice purpose, but interesting thing happened.  I was originally trying to write a C++ code, however I forgot include streamio library and using namespace std, then I just using printf() function all the way during my coding.

I think the most confusing part to me is I use .cpp extension and compile this program using VS 2015 compiler but I actually wrote in C style. Could someone tell me do I wrote a C or C++ code?

Here is the source code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
}node;

node *create()
{
    int i = 0;
    // Each variable must be assign to some value in the function
    node *head, *p, *q = NULL;
    int x = 0;
    head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Please input the data: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
        if (x == 0)
            break;
        p = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        p->data = x;
        if (++i == 1) {
            head->next = p;
        }
        else
        {
            q->next = p;
        }
        q = p;
    }
    q->next = NULL; 
    return head;
}

void printList(node head)
{
    node *tmp = &head;
    int counter = 0;
    printf("Print out the list: \n");
    while (tmp->next != NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        counter++;
        //surprise to me printf() is pretty advance...
        printf("%d item in the list: %d\n",counter, tmp->data);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printList(*create());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There in no C++ in the code, so rename the file with the proper extension `.C` and compile with a C compiler.

Comment: This definitively looks like C. While I suspect it would compile with a C++ compiler, this is not how things should be done in that language.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `.C` is C++ code, too! You mean lowercase `.c`?

Comment: @Olaf: The use of `"stdafx.h"` implies that the OP is compiling on Windows, where `foo.c` and `foo.C` are the same file. I don't believe that Windows compilers treat `.C` as C++ code.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That likely because Windows does not differentiate the case in filenames. Making this only bad practice on Windows, but incompatible to POSIX environments.

Comment: @Olaf: So what? The question is not about POSIX. Do not assume that `.C` implies C++ code; as far as I know even POSIX doesn't specify that. It's a compiler-specific convention.

Comment: I don't know why this question is getting so many downvotes and close votes. It's not a great question, but it seems clear enough, and I think it has a clear and correct answer.

Comment: @Olaf so sorry, my despised system has case-insensitive file names.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Popint is I have seen a lot of `.C` files with C++ code, but none with C code. This might be an outdated habit, but nevertheless it will confuse certain compilers. So why take the risk although even Windows allows to use lowercase `.c`?

Comment: @Olaf: Sure, but you said "`.C` is C++ code too!". That's not correct in all environments, and in particular it's probably incorrect in the OP's environment. If I see `FOO.C` in a Windows environment, it's probably a C source file.

Comment: @KeithThompson: From your previous comments you understood what I meant: `.C` signals the compiler frontend it is C++ code, so it will use the C++ compiler, too. Once more: why take the risk and not use the common extension `.c`. This will not be confused onm any system.

Comment: Why anyone would name a `.cpp` file as `.C` and not `.CPP` is beyond me. That could imply C++ is a grander version of C ... when as you bang on, it is a different langauge.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It was quite common years ago. Also see the gcc documentation (AFAIK at least clang will handle it similar): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b Agreed it might be irrelevant on Windows (not sure about gcc on Windows, though), but why take the risk?

Comment: @Olaf I never knew about that: I just happened to type the extension `.C` while thinking ahead to type the language`C`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: When two worlds collide ;-)

Comment: @Olaf should I talk about the language `c`? Is the language `C` a synonym for `c++`?

Comment: @WeatherVane: How about a tag "C/C++". and auto-close of questions with this tag? Might save a lot of discussions ... (I have no idea why `.C` was used for C++. I never did, nor did I use `.H` for C++ headers.)

Comment: @Olaf that has my vote. But I am curious: is there a difference between files with the extension `.cpp` and `.CPP`?

Comment: Hmm, another supporter for that idea ... If I just would not bue scared by meta-discussions that much. (yeah, I'm aware of the irony considering how tough I discuss, but that is a different sort).

Comment: @WeatherVane: I have no idea. Just know that `.c` was used commonly. Have not seen it recent code, though. And as I wrote, I don't support it. That is a minefield of legacies no one dares to touch. Jut like aliasing via `char`.

Comment: @Olaf: I may or may not have understood what you meant. What I *thought* you meant by "`.C` is C++ code, too!" is that `.C` unconditionally implies C++, which is incorrect. On re-reading your previous comment, perhaps you meant that `.C` can *also* be C++, i.e., that it's ambiguous, which is correct. (gcc on Linux treats `foo.C` as C++. I presume that a Windows compiler that uses the extension to determine the language would treat `foo.C` as C. MacOS also commonly has case-insensitive file systems; I don't know what's done there.)

Comment: @Olaf: FWIW, gcc on Linux treats `.cc`, `.cp`, `.cxx`, `.cpp`, `.CPP`, `.c++`, and `.C` as C++. It *doesn't* recognize `.CC`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: My fault. I should learn not to assume to much from the othere side (no offence, really on my side!). It is only what the compiler-frontend for a multilanguage-compiler uses to decide which language-specific backend to call (I'm aware this "backend" is actually the _frontend_ of the language-specific compiler:). Thus my strong recommendation to use lowercae `.c` to be unambiguous.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Of course `.C` does not magically make C++ code rfrom C code; for invalid syntax gcc will still complain. However, as it assumes C++, it will apply C++ semantics for code which is vaild in both languages **syntactically and grammatically**.  This can result in "unexpected" behaviour. due to different **semantics**. And as I did not participate in the development of gcc, I'm not to blame it does not accept `.CC`. I don't think this will be recognised as "the file is C" either. Personally, I use the common extensions `.c` (lowercase;-) and `.cpp`

Comment: All you have to do is put it through a `C++` compiler to see if it is legal `C++` and put it through a `C` compiler to see if it is legal `C`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is, as far as I can tell, valid C++.  It is not valid C, but could be made valid C with only a little effort.

C is *nearly* a subset of C++, but there is valid C code that is not valid C++ code -- and of course there's *plenty* of valid C++ code that's not valid C code.

The one thing that makes your code invalid as C is the use of the name `node`:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
}node;
```

In C++, the `struct node` definition makes the type visible either as `struct node` or as `node`. In C, the `struct` definition by itself only creates the name `struct node`. The name `node` is not visible until the `typedef` is complete -- which it isn't at the point where you define `node *next;`.

If you rename your source file with a `.c` suffix and compile it as C, the compiler will complain that `node` is an unknown type name.